# STI in rails with many-to-many relationship in the child classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I have 2 models `UnitPlate` & `PlantPlate` which are a part of STI(Single table inheritance).  I need many-to-many association with them.  Is the below way of has_many: through and STI correct.  I have the below models.  Facing some issues in migrations with the below approach

**`Parent Model`**

```
class Plate < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

**`Submodel 1`**

```
class UnitPlate < Plate

  has_many :unit_and_plant_plates, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :plant_plates, through: :unit_and_plant_plates

end
```

**`Submodel 2`**

```
class PlantPlate < Plate

  has_many :unit_and_plant_plates, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :unit_plates, through: :unit_and_plant_plates

end
```

**`Associated Model`**

```
class UnitAndPlantPlate < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :unit_plate
    belongs_to :plant_plate
end
```

**`Migration`**

```
class CreateTableUnitAndPlantPlates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :unit_and_plant_plates do |t|
      t.belongs_to :unit_plate
      t.belongs_to :plant_plate
      t.timestamps
     end
    add_index :unit_and_plant_plates, :unit_plate_id
    add_index :unit_and_plant_plates, :plant_plate_id
   end
end
```

Error during migrations

```
rake aborted!
/Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:16:in `block in trace_on': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `map'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `trace_on'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:340:in `trace'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:187:in `display_error_message'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:174:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rake:19:in `load'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Is this way of defining the has_many through correct?

Comment: What issues are you experiencing with migrations?

Comment: @Beerlington, updated the ques with error

Comment: I'd put a debugger in `/Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:16`, search for the variable holding the invalid US-ASCII sequence, and follow it up the stack.

Comment: guys the problem i see is with the implementation.  The other migrations work.  It will be great if you can review the approach that i have used.  I am not confident if it's right

Comment: @AnkitG Did you ever solve this? I just ran into the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class CreateTableUnitAndPlantPlates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :unit_and_plant_plates do |t|
      t.integer :unit_plate_id
      t.integer :plant_plate_id
      t.timestamps
     end
    add_index :unit_and_plant_plates, :unit_plate_id
    add_index :unit_and_plant_plates, :plant_plate_id
   end
end
```

Comment: I tried this, but this won't work as this is an STI pattern, there is nothing like a `unit_plates` or `plant_plates`.